# add day and month to bibliography using biblatex with bibtex backend

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, date

I'm using a setup with biblatex/natbib and bibtex and I would like to add day and month to the bibliography. Is there a simply way to do this?

With my MWE below, I currently get - with not day and month,

[image: ga me data a mont]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            dateabbrev=false,
            style=authoryear,
            natbib=true]%
                          {biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
unpublished{Book,
  title = {This is a Title},
  author = {Author, Some},
  note={This is a note about this specific version}
  date = 2005,
  month = feb,
  day = 14,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

Cf. \citep[19]{Book}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't `date = {2005-02-14}` work? `day` is not a recognised field. And if you use `date` it overrules the `month`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the `date` field with `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```
@unpublished{Book,
  title  = {This is a Title},
  author = {Author, Some},
  note   = {This is a note about this specific version},
  date   = {2005-02-14},
}
```

But then you will still not see the full date in the bibliography. This has to do with the `mergedate` settings, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/520

At the moment, `mergedate=false`, `minimum` or `basic` will give you the full date.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Simply adding `      mergedate=false` solved my problem. I have all my bib entries with `day` and `month`.

Comment: @EricFail Ah yes, it could be that BibTeX still supports `day`. It is not officially supported any more, however, and Biber ignores it now.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I've mostly gone with whatever [BibDesk](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/) _invited me to do_. I'll look into the recommended approach. Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: @EricFail I'm not familiar with citation managers. But maybe BibDesk has a dedicated `biblatex`-mode. I have seen situations where citation managers would deliver sub-par output. The recommended format can be found in the `biblatex` documentation. But of course that is a lot to stomach.